# Newline character '\n' ignored in textarea element in Safari after Mac OS Mojave update

Tags: html, safari

I have a textarea element on my website with a placeholder value containing '\n' characters in between the text to make it look neatly formatted.

This worked perfectly fine until I — unknowingly — decided to update my Mac OS to the latest version called 'Mojave'.

After the update Safari starting throwing all kinds of hissy fits. My guess is that these are all consequences of their new 'security' updates.

I double checked and it works perfectly fine in Chrome, but in Safari the textarea placeholder text seems to ignore the newline characters after the update...

Anyone else seeing this? Exact Safari version is 12.0.2 (14606.3.4).

Here's the textarea element with all its atributes (written in Pug code):

```
textarea(id="invitation-emails" name="textarea" rows="12" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" placeholder="ambassador@example.com\nambassador@example.com\nambassador@example.com\n.\n.\n.")
```